# Flutter - AlertDialog pops up without showing its content

Tags: flutter, dart, android-alertdialog

I'am building an app in Flutter and, to improve its looks and smoothness in general, I decided to create a custom AlertDialog that has an animation when popping up. Unfortunately, it's presenting an error that I cannot figure out how to solve: sometimes, when I click on the button that makes the CustomAlertDialog pop up, it does that perfectly; however, there are some other times when the widget simply pops up completely blank, without showing its content. I've attached two images that demonstrate this behaviour, as well as the code for the CustomAlertDialog widget and the button I use to make it pop up.

How can I solve that?

Image without the error [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IP9mK.jpg

Image with the error    [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/shvQM.jpg

Here's the code I used to create the CustomAlertDialog:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomAlertDialog extends StatefulWidget {

  String titulo;
  String texto;
  String textoBotao1;
  String textoBotao2;
  final VoidCallback funcaoBotao1;
  final VoidCallback funcaoBotao2;

  CustomAlertDialog({Key key, @required this.texto, @required this.titulo,
    this.textoBotao1, this.textoBotao2, this.funcaoBotao1, this.funcaoBotao2}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CustomAlertDialogState createState() => _CustomAlertDialogState();
}

class _CustomAlertDialogState extends State<CustomAlertDialog> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  AnimationController controller;
  Animation<double> animacaoEscala;

  @override
  void initState() {

    controller = AnimationController(
        vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 550));

    animacaoEscala = CurvedAnimation(parent: controller, curve: Curves.elasticInOut);
    super.initState();

    controller.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
      });
    });

    controller.forward();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Material(
        color: Colors.transparent,
        child: ScaleTransition(
          scale: animacaoEscala,
          child: AlertDialog(
            elevation: 2,
            title: Text(widget.titulo),
            content: Text(widget.texto,
              textAlign: TextAlign.start,),
            actions: <Widget>[
              widget.textoBotao1 != null ? FlatButton(
                child: Text('${widget.textoBotao1}', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.indigo),),
                onPressed: widget.funcaoBotao1,
              ) : SizedBox.shrink(),
              widget.textoBotao2 != null ? FlatButton(
                child: Text('${widget.textoBotao2}', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.indigo),),
                onPressed: widget.funcaoBotao2,
              ) : SizedBox.shrink(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And here's the code of the button I use to pop up this CustomAlertDialog:

```
Container(
                  height: sizeConfig.blockSizeVertical*30,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.redAccent,
                  ),
                  child: Material(
                    color: Colors.transparent,
                    child: InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        showDialog(context: context,
                            builder: (BuildContext context){
                              return CustomAlertDialog(
                                  texto: '\nTem certeza de que deseja sair?',
                                  titulo: 'Sair',
                              textoBotao1: 'Não',
                              textoBotao2: 'Sim',
                              funcaoBotao1: ()
                              {Navigator.pop(context);},
                              funcaoBotao2: () async {
                                await fazerLogout(context);
                              },);
                            });
                      },
                      splashColor: Colors.white,
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Icon(Icons.logout, color: Colors.white, size: sizeConfig.blockSizeVertical*14,),
                          Text('Sair', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: sizeConfig.blockSizeVertical*12))
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
```

Comment: Is it possible to share the error log? as the code seems working fine in my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

While you are using the correct widget to handle the animation (scaling) part for your `AlertDialog`, you are missing the part which handles the corresponding rebuilds while animating. Currently your dialog tree is:

```dart
child: Material(
  color: Colors.transparent,
  child: ScaleTransition(
    scale: animacaoEscala,
    child: AlertDialog(
```

You need to wrap your `ScaleTransition` widget with the `AnimatedBuilder` widget, which gets the actual `AnimationController` and rebuilds when the controller is active / animating:

```dart
child: Material(
  color: Colors.transparent,
  child: AnimatedBuilder(
    animation: controller,
    child: ScaleTransition(
      scale: animacaoEscala,
      child: AlertDialog(
```

Comment: I tried this, but I keep getting the same error. Any other idea that I may try?

Comment: Remove the addListener function in initState while using my approach and try it again - if it still does not work: show the error message please!

Comment: I removed the addListener function, but the issue keeps happening. And also, the log shows no error message. 
I also tried to change the duration of the animation on the CustomAlertDialog widget to 600ms, and the problem disappeared when running in debug mode. However, when I run the app in profile mode, the widget pops up blank every single time.